# Accessing AWS Cloudfront Headers in Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sam

I am trying to create an API (either REST or HTTP API) on AWS that points to some lambda function that can then access the Cloudfront HTTP headers described here:

[Adding the CloudFront HTTP headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html)

I have been struggling to get these headers added all day.  I have tried the following:

1. Cloudfront distribution that points to Http API with a lambda function as a route.  The cloudfront distribution has an origin request policy as follows:

[image]

When I test this, I have no cloudfront headers appearing in the request (when I print the headers in the lambda function).

2. When I try to do the same setup with a REST API, I am able to see the "CloudFront-Viewer-Country" and "CloudFront-Viewer-ASN" but don't see any other cloudfront headers, even with the above origin request policy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work without API Gateway by following this tutorial:

[Using Amazon CloudFront with AWS Lambda as origin to accelerate your web applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-aws-lambda-as-origin-to-accelerate-your-web-applications/)

Then applying the above origin request policy.  Still not sure how to get it to work with API Gateway.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the similar issue but the point to note here is you need to tell cloudfront which header you want to pass through.

I believe it is related to security reasons.

So allow the specific header in cloudfront as custom and then that header will be available in lambda.

Example -

https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/11/add-custom-header-in-cloudfrontpass.html

Comment: The link to kuchbhilearning is not a safe website. I would recommend that you don't click on the link.